# How to duplicate a Woocommerce product and include the WooThemes Per Product Shipping entries?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I am using Woocommerce together with the WooThemes Per Product Shipping plugin.

The problem I have is that when using the “Duplicate” a product feature in Woocommerce, the PPS entries are not copied over to the new product.

Can anyone help in what I would need to add to the following file to get this to work?
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-duplicate-product.php

The PPS entries are stored in the following table:
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/471866/f815997f78d9f2505919db880ffe35b5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code,

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_duplicate_product', 'wdm_duplicate_pps_entries',10,2);

function wdm_duplicate_pps_entries( $new_id, $post) {
   global $wpdb;
   $id = isset( $_REQUEST['post'] ) ? absint( $_REQUEST['post'] ) : '';
   if(!empty($id)) {
   $query = "Select * From " . $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_per_product_shipping_rule 
   Where product_id = '" . $id . "'";

   $result = $wpdb->results($query);
   $table_name =  $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_per_product_shipping_rule";

   foreach($result as $single_result) {

      $data = array('product_id' => $new_id, 'rule_country' => $single_result->rule_country, 'rule_state' => $single_result->rule_state,'rule_postcode' => $single_result->rule_postcode,'rule_cost' => $single_result->rule_cost,'rule_item_cost' => $single_result->rule_item_cost,'rule_order' => $single_result->rule_order);

     $wpdb->insert($table_name,$data);
   }

   }
}
```

Comment: I tried that code in my theme functions.php file and I get the following error message: Fatal error: Call to undefined method wpdb::results()

Comment: Correct method name is, get_results(). Just replace - $result = $wpdb->results($query);  with -- $result = $wpdb->get_results($query); Sorry for typo mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: For what it's worth the action is renamed to `woocommerce_product_duplicate` now.

Comment: Hey WisdmLabs, I am having this same issue however the code you have provided does not work for me? If you could help that would be so appreciated! Here is my question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948904/woocommerce-when-duplicating-a-product-it-does-not-copy-per-product-shipping-i